# XPM choosing wrong deployer for publishing

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

We have a DD4T website in Tridion 2013, publication for which lists 2 deployer(one for dd4t and one non-dd4t). But Finish Editing is choosing the non DD4T deployer for publishing. Is it correct?

I checked the storage config for both the deployers and only the dd4t one has the pub of my website. So it should have chosen it for publishing. Am I correct? If not, then how the site edit makes a choice?

```
Unable to update the changes using OData Service. An error occurred while processing this request.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> 
<code></code> 
<message xml:lang="en-US">The input data was invalid: Content field required., 
  Content field required., Content field required.</message> 
</error>
```

**This is the odata cd_core Log details:**

2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG SessionServiceImpl - Loadin...

2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG SessionServiceImpl - Loading previewSessionItems and previewSessionPublicationMappings for session ff7cdee1-100b-4166-9699-07e1e39a4341.

2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG JPAPreviewSessionItemDAO - Retrieving PreviewSessionItems by sessionId: ff7cdee1-100b-4166-9699-07e1e39a4341.

2014-05-21 10:05:21,296 DEBUG JPAPublicationMappingDAO - Retrieving PublicationMapping by mappingKey: ff7cdee1-100b-4166-9699-07e1e39a4341.

**2014-05-21 10:05:21,312 DEBUG JPAItemDAO - Removing binary meta from storage

2014-05-21 10:05:21,328 ERROR SessionWrapperFactory - Exception while cleaning-up session data: Error while committing the transaction, Error while committing the transaction**

2014-05-21 10:06:20,948 DEBUG HttpModule - Dispose 8:20 AM

Answer (score 2):

XPM will use the Publication Target that has the current URL listed in the Session Preview tab. If there are multiple such Targets, it will use the one that has the best match with the URL (i.e. is more specific; has a longer URL match).

It does not look at the storage configuration of that system.

Comment: Thanks! if both of them have exactly the same URL then will it check the last published info for the deployer? Also am I getting the error (updated in the original post above) for the deployer

Comment: No, if they both have the same URL it will pick the first one it encounters. The error is likely due to misconfiguration of the OData web service you configured. Try going directly to that URL in your browser and see what kind of errors you get (try getting a list of Publications for example)

Comment: The webservice is opening with no error and starts with -This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service.

Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

If you have access to the service, you can enable metadata publishing by completing the following steps to modify your web or application configuration file:....                         I have pasted the cd_core log for odata above. Please suggest.

Comment: That's the standard .NET message for a service that doesn't expose its metadata. Try actually using the service, by adding /Publications to the end (after odata.svc) and see if that gives an error.

Comment: I can see my pub listed along with the other in xml format. I have also checked the session preview's dbo.Page_Content table, nothing is getting entered on Update Preview for my pub.